# Websocket example in haskell uses special characters as functions

Tags: haskell, websocket, ghc

```
> type Client = (Text, WS.Connection)
The state kept on the server is simply a list of connected clients. We've added
an alias and some utility functions, so it will be easier to extend this state
later on.
> type ServerState = [Client]
Check if a user already exists (based on username):
> clientExists :: Client -> ServerState -> Bool
> clientExists client = any ((== fst client) . fst)
Remove a client:
> removeClient :: Client -> ServerState -> ServerState
> removeClient client = filter ((/= fst client) . fst)
```

This is a literal haskell code taken from [websockets](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/server.lhs#L47). I don't understand how does `clientExists` function works,

```
clientExists client = any ((== fst client) . fst)
```

This function is invoked as,

```
clientExists client clients
```

So, how does the function refer the second argument `clients`? and what does `.` operator do?

And again at [removeClient](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/server.lhs#L58), what does the operator `/=' stand for?

Comment: `.` is "compose". `/=` is "not equal". Since these functions are defined in the Prelude, you can find out more about them by firing up GHCi and running `:info (.)` or `:i (/=)`. Another way to learn about them is to [search on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` operator is the function composition operator, it's defined as

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

The `/=` operator is "not equals", usually written as `!=` in other languages.

The `clientExists` function has two arguments, but the second one is left off since it's redundant.  It could have been written as

```
clientExists client clients = all ((== fst client) . fst) clients
```

But Haskell allows you to drop the last argument in situations like this.  The `any` function has the type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, and the function `any ((== fst client) . fst)` has the type `[a] -> Bool`.  This is saying that the function `clientExists client` is the same function as `any ((== fst client) . fst)`.

Another way to think of it is that Haskell does not have multi-argument functions, only single argument functions that return new functions.  This is because `->` is right associative, so a type signature like

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

Can be written as

```
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

without changing its meaning.  With the second type signature it's more clear that you have a function that when given an `a`, returns a function of type `b -> (c -> d)`.  If it's next given a `b`, it returns a function of type `c -> d`.  Finally, if this is given a `c` it just returns a `d`.  Since function application in Haskell is so cheap (just a space), this is transparent, but it comes in handy.  For example, it means that you can write code like

```
incrementAll = map (+1)
```

or

```
onlyPassingStudents = filter ((>= 70) . grade)
```

In both of these cases I've also used *operator sections*, where you can supply either argument to an operator, and so long as its wrapped in parens it works.  Internally it looks more like

```
(x +) = \y -> x + y
(+ x) = \y -> y + x
```

Where you can swap out the `+` for any operator you please.  If you were to expand the definition of `clientExists` to have all argument specified it would look more like

```
clientExists client clients = any (\c -> fst c == fst client) clients
```

This definition is exactly equivalent to the one you have, just de-sugared to what the compiler really uses internally.

Comment: Going the other way there is `clientExists = any . (. fst) . (==) . fst`, but I'm not really a fan of that level of pointfree code.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use the GHCi interpreter to find out the types of the functions.

First off, the `/=` operator is the not-equal:

```
ghci> :t (/=)
(/=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
ghci> 5 /= 5
False
ghci> 10 /= 5
True
```

`.` is the composition of two functions. It glues two functions together, just like in mathematics:

```
ghci> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
ghci> :t head.tail
head.tail :: [c] -> c
ghci> (head.tail) [1, 2, 3]
2
```

With the basics covered, let's see how it is used in your function definition:

```
ghci> :t (\x -> (== fst x))
(\x-> (== fst x)) :: Eq a => (a, b) -> a -> Bool
ghci> :t (\x-> (== fst x) . fst)
(\x-> (== fst x) . fst) :: Eq b => (b, b1) -> (b, b2) -> Bool
ghci> (\x -> (== fst x) . fst) (1, "a") (1, "b")
True
ghci> (\x -> (== fst x) . fst) (1, "a") (2, "b")
False
```

As we can see, the `(== fst x) . fst` is used to take two tuples, and compare the first element each for equality. Now, this expression (let's call it `fstComp`) has type `fstComp :: Eq b => (b, b1) -> (b, b2) -> Bool`, but we are already passing it a defined tuple (`client :: (Text, WS.Connection)`), we curry it to `(Text, b2) -> Bool`.

Since we have `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, we can unify the first parameter with the previous type to have an expression of type `(Text, b2) -> [(Text, b2)] -> Bool`. Instantiating `b2 = WS.Connection` we get the type of `clientExists :: (Text, WS.Connection) -> [(Text, WS.Connection)] -> Bool`, or using the type synonyms, `clientExists :: Client -> ServerState -> Bool`.